# Changing background of ckeditor text area with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, ckeditor

How can I change dynamically the background image of CKEditor using jQuery Adapter?
I've got a list of images and whenever the user clicks over one of them, I want to change the background image of the editor area with that image. What I'm trying is:

```
$('#editor_content').ckeditor();
var editorInstance = $('#editor_content').ckeditor().editor;
$('img').click(function(ev){
editorInstance.setData('<style type="text/css"> body{ background-image: url(' + $(this).attr('src') + '); </style>');
});
```

That works fine, in the sense that it changes its background image. However, if the user press backspace then it disappears. I think that's because the style its added in the body directly:

```
<p>
<style type="text/css"> 
body
{ 
    background-image: url(path/to/my/image.png); 
} 
</style>
</p>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a contenteditable element instead of a textarea?

Comment: It's a very good options but I'll prefer to have rich text editing tools

Comment: Ckeditor supports contenteditable: [http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline)

Comment: I've tried using a contenteditable div with a prefixed size and resize_enabled option set to false. It works fine but if I press enter to many times (until I reach the end of the div) it creates a new div for each enter key stroke

Comment: @Allonsy, I have the same problem, when press enter or using `ul` or `li`.Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

As you've found, adding a new element in the content of the editor is a bad idea, instead you must get the body element of the editor and change its styles.

```
$('img').click(function(ev){
    editorInstance.getDocument().getBody().setStyle("background-image", "url(' + $(this).attr('src') + ')");
});
```

But this change will be saved only if you work in "full-page" mode, otherwise, the editor only returns the contents of the body and not the rest of the document.

Comment: Yes, that's how I finally managed. I've found that we can access the styles by doing `code` editorInstance.document.getBody().getStyle('background-image');`code`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('keypress','.editor-content', function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 8) {
    editorInstance.setData('<style type="text/css"> body{ background-image: url(' + $(this).attr('src') + '); </style>');
   }
});
```

when user press the backspace key, update editor's background property again.

Answer (score 0):

This approach will also work for new images inserted in your editor ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/um1vgpp1/)):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea', {
    on: {
        contentDom: function() {
            this.editable().on( 'click', function( evt ) {                   
                this.setStyle( 'background-image', 'url(' + evt.data.getTarget().getAttribute( 'src' ) + ')' );
            } );            
        }
    }
} );
```

With jQuery adapter:

```
$( 'textarea' ).ckeditor( {
    contentDom: function() {
        ...
    }
} );
```

See [`editor#contentDom`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-contentDom) event.